# ffmpeg and png watermark issue

Tags: ffmpeg, png, watermark

I tried to create a watermark (using a png image) on a video like this:

```
ffmpeg -i test.wmv -b:a 300k -ar 22050 -t 10 -f flv -s 352x288 -vf "movie = watermark_logo352.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay =0:0 [out]" out.flv
```

but I get the error:

```
ffmpeg version 0.10.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jun 14 2012 13:14:31 with gcc 4.4.5   configuration:
--prefix=/home/username --enable-cross-compile --enable-shared --arch=amd64 --target-os=linux --disable-yasm --enable-decoder=png --enable-encoder=png   
        libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100   
        libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100   
        libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100   
        libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100   
        libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100   
        libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100   
        libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100 
        Input #0, asf, from 'test.wmv':   
        Metadata:
            >     WMFSDKVersion   : 9.00.00.2980
            >     WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
            >     IsVBR           : 1
            >     VBR Peak        : 351
            >     Buffer Average  : 728   Duration: 00:00:05.59, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 574 kb/s
            >     Stream #0:0(jpn): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 22050 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 32 kb/s
            >     Stream #0:1(jpn): Video: wmv1 (WMV1 / 0x31564D57), yuv420p, 352x288, 520 kb/s, SAR 8:9 DAR 88:81, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc File
            > 'out2.flv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y w:352 h:288
            > pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:8/9 sws_param: 
    [image2 @ 0x551f880] decoding for stream 0 failed 
    [image2 @ 0x551f880] Could not find codec parameters (Video: png) 
    [movie @ 0x551f440] Failed to find stream info
    [movie @ 0x551f440] Failed to find any codec 
    Error initializing filter 'movie' with args 'watermark_logo352.png' 
    Error opening filters!
```

When I use a jpg, it works like a charm.

I'm use ffmpeg v 0.10.4 on Debian 6 Squeeze. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

The problem is simpler than i thought. If i use ffmpeg -i  with any png image i get a similar error:

```
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[image2 @ 0xc8b73a0] decoding for stream 0 failed
[image2 @ 0xc8b73a0] Could not find codec parameters (Video: png)
watermark.png: could not find codec parameters
```

Answer (score 2):

For me installing `zlib-devel.x86_64` or something alike helped, e.g. `zlib1g-dev` on Debian.

Try

```
apt-search zlib
```

or

```
yum search zlib
```

Comment: Per the duplicate on Stack Overflow this is the solution indeed.